# Did Logan intentionally pay off Yukio's prophecy?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, logan, the-wolverine

In *The Wolverine*, Yukio is a mutant that has the power to see how people she touches are going to die. At one point in the movie, she tells Logan that she saw his death:

> I saw you die, holding your own heart in your hand.

In that movie, this scene leads into one where Logan

> literally operates on himself by removing his own heart

but while he flatlines, he obviously doesn't die. This leads the viewer to suspect that Yukio's vision must have been confused by Logan's healing factor, and the whole "prophecy" never comes up again.

Fast forward to the end of *Logan*, and we see:

> Logan dying, holding Laura's hand in his own.

**Was this scene shot intentionally so that it paid off Yukio's prophecy, or was this just coincidental?**

Answer (score 37):

## Yes

**James Mangold**, who is the Writer and Director of the movie *[Logan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logan_(film))* as well as the Director of *[The Wolverine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logan_(film))*, [confirms on Twitter](https://twitter.com/mang0ld/status/839888687227789312) that he *did* intend that as foreshadowing the whole time!!

Twitter user "MauriceTheChosenOne" [questions](https://twitter.com/_moegonzales3_/status/839874304183435265) James Mangold about this very setup:
[image: Screen capture of a Twitter status posted by user "MauriceTheChosenOne" which has screen captures from the scene in "The Wolverine" where the character Yukio tells Logan/Wolverine that she has foreseen his death, reading "I see you on your back, there's blood everywhere. You're holding your own heart in your hand.". With the second screen capture depicting the final scene in *Logan* where a dying Logan is holding onto Laura's (X-23) hand; the implication being that she is his cloned daughter, and therefore Logan's "heart". The 'feels' are incredible!]

To which Mangold [replies](https://twitter.com/mang0ld/status/839883693392977920):

> Well done Maurice

And later [announces](https://twitter.com/mang0ld/status/839883693392977920):

[image: Screen capture from Twitter with Writer/Director, James Mangold, saying "And the prize goes to Maurice!", followed by a link to Maurice's original tweet [pasted above].]

[And here's an earlier Twitter convo where James confirms the theory.](https://twitter.com/mang0ld/status/839883411544145920)

I shall give you a few moments to gather your feels and collect your jaws from the floor.

Comment: To be fair, unless there's more background evidence (which is unlikely to ever surface), this could have just been a "Sure Why Not" from what is actually a happy coincidence (that is, this interpretation is just too good to pass up). For starters, if Yukio literally *sees* someone's death, it's extremely improbable she'd describe his death poetically as "holding his heart" rather than, you know, "holding a little girl's hand". If the prophecy hadn't been resolved in *The Wolverine* (albeit via a quibble), the argument for it would be stronger. Not to diminish the observation itself, of course.

Comment: @JeroenMostert my question was more about _Logan_ itself... I'm skeptical that Mangold shot _Wolverine_ with _Logan_ in mind, as he claims, but I'm perfectly willing to accept that he shot the death scene with the earlier "prophecy" in mind.

Comment: @KutuluMike: I'm not saying he didn't, I'm just saying he'd be a fool not to lie and *say* he did even if he didn't, so him merely claiming "yes, that's right, well spotted" doesn't do it for me. As I said, though, there's almost certainly no other way to verify this as Mangold probably didn't lock away some evidence that he had this idea before shooting, just to appease buzzkill skeptics like me. :-)

Comment: @Jeroen I agree. The problem is that since Mangold said yes, that's all we have to go by. I could have included a little sentence about those exact thoughts, but I decided not to.